# Socket File Transfer sending incomplete files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcpclient, file-transfer

I am trying my hands on Socket programming in C# (.NET). I have referred to a couple of examples from codeproject, but my file transfer always sends out incomplete data.

Data of very very small sizes works fine like 1kB. But larger files get transferred incomplete, specifically images.

Here's my client code, that sends a file to the server. The clientData stores the binary of the file.

```
byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + fileName);
            byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
            byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);

            fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
            fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
            fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);

            curMsg = "Connection to server ...";
            clientSock.Connect(ipEnd);
            int count;
            curMsg = "File sending...";
            count = clientSock.Send(clientData);
            MessageBox.Show(count+" "+clientData.Length);

            curMsg = "Disconnecting...";
            clientSock.Close();
```

While here is my code for the server, that receives the file.

```
                sock.Listen(100);

            curMsg = "Running and waiting to receive file.";
            Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();

            byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * 5000];

            int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);
            curMsg = "Receiving data...";

            int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
            string fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);

            BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath +"/"+ fileName, FileMode.Append)); ;
            bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen);

            curMsg = "Saving file...";

            bWrite.Close();
            clientSock.Close();
```

What is funny is, that when I set a break-point at 'send' on the client, the file gets transferred fine. I am observing the byte counts at both ends and the transfer bytes match when I use a break-point, while when I don't the received bytes are lower than transferred bytes at client.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you upload the code you written to send data in chunks?

Comment: The overload of Close() you are using does not wait for send/receive to "finish" you must use the overload that has a timeout so it has time to "purge" your outgoing stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to implement a protocol! To use TCP, you have to design and implement a protocol that defines what bytes will be sent and how the receiver will identify messages or protocol data elements. You haven't done any of this. Your receive code has no way to know whether it has received the entire file or not because there's no protocol to tell it nor any code to implement such a protocol. So of course it gets it wrong -- it has no way to get it right.

If `receivedBytesLen` is 1, your code fails horribly.

Comment: Hi David. thanks for pointing that out
I am using the following code for initializing the socket, I assumed that ProtocolType.IP would help.
`ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5656);
           sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
           sock.Bind(ipEnd);`

Comment: I changed the ProtocolType.Ip to ProtocolType.Tcp. Still no luck. I am absolute beginner, could please you be specific.

Comment: You didn't understand my answer at all. You are trying to send a file. TCP is not a protocol for transferring a file, it's a protocol for transferring bytes. To transfer a file, you need a protocol to transfer a file. Before you write even a single line of code, you should design such a protocol and document it.

Comment: Sorry about that - actually both answers got me through my problem. You are right. I did not have a protocol in place to let the client know about the file size. So it worked on hard coded byte lengths. Solved the issue later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying Network or TCP layer may not always send the whole file as one single chunk. You might try doing a while loop till you receive the exact/complete length of the file.

To do this, you might need to send the length of the file first.

And yes this may work in debug mode, but may differ during runtime.

Comment: Thanks Muthu,
To begin with I tried hardcoding the file size. Received the bits correctly. The buffer gets overwritten.

Comment: Yes, you need to append this to another byte array or List<Byte> and it should not overwrite after this.